# Default Iterable plus other Iterable

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I would like to have a class with some methods returning different Iterable like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  ...

  public Iterable<T> iterable1() {
    return new Iterable1<T>();
  }

  public Iterable<T> iterable2() {
    return new Iterable2<T>();
  }

  public Iterable<T> iterable3() {
    return new Iterable3<T>();
  }

}
```

But I also want a default Iterable for the class MyClass (let's say Iterable1).
I know that I could make MyClass extend Iterable and implement the default policy inside it, but I do not want to do that because I want a clean interface.

I want to be able to write:

```
for(T t : myClass) //Here it should use Iterable1
  //do something
```

or

```
for(T t : myClass.iterable1()) //Here it should use Iterable1 again
  //do something
```

and

```
for(T t : myClass.iterable2()) //Here it uses Iterable2
  //do something
```

and so on.
I can not think of many pattern for accomplish this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your top level class needs to implement `Iterable`. The `Iterable` interface defines a method

```
Iterator<T> iterator();
```

which will provide the 'default' iterator in your case.

Your class would need to look a little like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
  ...

  Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterable1<T>().iterator();
  }

  public Iterable<T> iterable1() {
   return new Iterable1<T>();
  }

  public Iterable<T> iterable2() {
   return new Iterable2<T>();
  }

  public Iterable<T> iterable3() {
   return new Iterable3<T>();
  }

}
```

Comment: I was thinking to use some tricks with extends. MyClass extends Iterable1 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work:

```
    MyClass myObject = ...
    for (T t : myObject) {
          ....
```

then `MyClass` *must* implement `Iterable<T>`.  [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) says:

> *"The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs."*

where *"the Expression"* is referring to `myObject`.

---

> I know that I could make MyClass extend (sic) Iterable and implement the default policy inside it, but I do not want to do that because I want a clean interface.

Sorry, but that is not possible in Java.  See above.

---

> I was thinking to use some tricks with extends. MyClass extends Iterable1 or something like that.

That is effectively the same as making `MyClass` implement `Iterable` ... assuming that `Iterable1` implements `Iterable`.